# How to create table from table with "case" in order to copy and modify original data in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle12c

Since I have a table with milions of records, I've been looking for a solution to update data in one column more efficiently, without using UNDO tablespace and UPDATE statement.

My idea was to create a second table (copy) X from the target table Y, as follows:

```
create table X as
select col1,col2,col3, (case when col4 is not null and createdate < sysdate - 180 then null else col4) as col4 from Y;
```

Then drop table Y and rename X to Y. It creates the table but my test query

```
select count(col4) from Y where col4 is not null and createdate < sysdate - 180
```

Shows that there are still some records with original value (looks like case clause does not work as suppose to). When I use the same select in subquery and the exact same condition, like

```
select count(col4) from (select col1,col2,col3, (case when col4 is not null and createdate < sysdate - 180 then null else col4) as col4 from Y) where col4 is not null and createdate < sysdate - 180
```

The result is 0. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: You don't want to use UNDO tablespace, but want to create a new table with millions of records? Why?

Comment: It's the database used only by me at the moment and I have sufficient amount of space. I would like more to do it "fastest" way. Also resizing UNDO is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I have figured that out:

The problem here is sysdate as I tried to at first clone the table (sysdate1) and then validate the data using sysdate in where conditions (sysdate2 different from the first one)

Subquery print 0 as it takes the same sysdate for both conditions.